# Buscar registros en base al año en curso

Tags: c#

tengo una gran duda.. saben  estado haciendo un programa en C# y MySQL, que registra movimientos de producción de una fabrica de muebles, la fabrica identifica sus productos por "LOTES", ahora cada que cambia el año se reinician lo lotes.

este es un ejemplo de los registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
bien como pueden ver yo capturo, quien lo hizo, en que area lo hizo, que articulo hizo, cuantos, cuantas horas, de que lote, lo demas se calcula por default...

bien mi pregunta es la siguiente, como les dije cada año reinician los lotes, como puedo validar que si por ejemplo

el lote "1" lo capturaron el día "01-01-2017" el sistema me diferencie de el lote "1" del "01-01-2018"

porque el sistema también lo que hace es que los lotes no se puedan repetir, para un control de los reportes de los empleados, aparte la tabla lotes tiene como key tanto el numero de lote como la fecha de creación, la tabla lote si me dejara repetir lotes siempre y cuando no se repitan las fechas es la forma que encontré de que se puedan reiniciar los lotes en esta parte, pero  en la tabla de producción como el ejemplo como le hago para que cuando se repitan los lotes la tabla solo me tome en cuenta los del año en curso por así decirlo...

Si no me explique haganmelo saber para explicarme mejor!!!

Comment: Pues no se si lo termino de entender...que problema hay en añadir el año al hacer la consulta? Es decir , `WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2017'` por ejemplo?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: exacto... muchas gracias por tu ayuda... como puedes ver soy nuevo en esto XD

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas filtrar por el año, lo que puedes usar es la función [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) de MySql. En tu caso, sería algo como:

```
WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2017'
```